# SQL Server Database unique number generation on any record insertion

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have like 11 columns in my database table and i am inserting data in 10 of them. i want to have a unique number like "1101 and so on" in the 11th column.
Any idea what should i do?? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it `auto_increment primary key` that you want (or whatever it's called in MSSQL)?

Comment: yes, i am talking about auto_increment primary key. but i want to set the start value from like "1100".

Comment: I recall, there's is a way to set a starting offset for the primary key. Forgot what it's called.

Comment: why 1101 in 11th column for first row.Will it be 1102 for second row ?
why it start with 1101 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server 2012 and above you can generate `Sequence`

```
Create SEQUENCE RandomSeq
start with 1001
increment by 1 
Go

Insert into YourTable(Id,col1...)
Select NEXT VALUE FOR RandomSeq,col1....
```

or else you can use `Identity`

```
Identity(seed,increment)
```

You can start the seed from 1101 and increment the sequence by 1

```
Create table YourTable 
(
   id INT IDENTITY(1101,1),
   Col varchar(10)
)
```

Comment: i am using SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Then use the `identity` to generate the sequence

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have that unique number in a different field then you can manipulate that field with primary key and insert that value.

If you want in primary key value, then open the table in design mode, go to 'Identity specification', set 'identity increment' and 'identity seed' as you want.

Alternatively you can use table script like,

```
CREATE TABLE Persons
(
ID int IDENTITY(12,1) PRIMARY KEY,
FName varchar(255) NOT NULL,

)
```

here the primary key will start seeding from 12 and seed value will be 1.

Answer (score 0):

If you have your table definition already in place you can alter the column and add Computed column marked as persisted as:

```
ALTER TABLE tablename drop column column11;
ALTER TABLE tablename add column11 as '11' 
+right('000000'+cast(ID as varchar(10)), 2) PERSISTED ;
--You can change the right operator value from 2 to any as per the requirements.
--Also replace ID with the identity column in your table.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
create table inc
(
id int identity(1100,1),
somec char
)
```